# When the CD4+ gets activated and help B cells, does it have to be the same pathogen?

Tags: immunology

Does the peptide (presented by the class II HLA molecule) that activates a CD4+ T cell need to be from the same pathogen as the antigen recognized by a B cell when the CD4+ T cell promotes the activation and differentiation of that B cell?

Comment: This is just a guess, and hence a comment. I don't know of any mechanism *preventing* it being from a different pathogen/source of antigen, but since co-infection is typically quite rare, it would be rather unusual to find a B cell recognizing one pathogen while taking up a completely different other one and presenting it via Class II MHC. You also need to keep in mind that the antigen recognized by the BCR and internalized by the B cell is directed into the MHC II processing pathway for presentation to T cells.

Comment: Yes I guess that makes sense, small question though, does the peptide presented via class II MHC _has_ to be from the pathogen the B cell recognizes? Can it not be something else? (if the B cell is infected by a virus, a peptide from that virus for example)